# Castle Windsor does not work under Medium Trust

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

When attempting to run an ASP.NET MVC application which uses Castle Windsor, the following error occurs.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member:
>   'Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.InitializeLifetimeService()'.
>   Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the
>   security accessibility of the method being overriden.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security
>   rules violated while overriding member:
>   'Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.InitializeLifetimeService()'.
>   Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the
>   security accessibility of the method being overriden.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while
>   overriding member:
>   'Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.InitializeLifetimeService()'.
>   Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the
>   security accessibility of the method being overriden.]
>   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer..ctor() +0

The assemblies `Castle.Core.dll` and `Castle.Windsor.dll` have been built off the source code available on [github](https://github.com/castleproject/). The source code for the assemblies includes the file `SecurityAssemblyInfo.cs` which has the following source code:

```
// Sets up assembly level security settings
#if ! SILVERLIGHT
[assembly: System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
#if DOTNET40
[assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level2)]
#endif
#endif
```

I have verified using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) that the `System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` attribute is declared at the assembly on both files.

The web application is being run with `<trust level="Medium" />`.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to get a successful build + run of my mvc application by making the following changes to **Castle.Core**:

#### SecurityAssemblyInfo.cs:

Changed to *only* the following:

> [assembly: System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
>   [assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]

#### ProxyGenerator.cs:

Changed three lines in ProxyGenerator::ProxyGenerator(IProxyBuilder):

```
if (HasSecurityPermission())
{
    Logger = new TraceLogger("Castle.DynamicProxy", LoggerLevel.Warn);
}
```

becomes:

```
// if (HasSecurityPermission())
// {
//    Logger = new TraceLogger("Castle.DynamicProxy", LoggerLevel.Warn);
// }
```

I have **no** idea what sort of consequences these might have. It would be nice if someone familiar with the SecurityRuleSets could chime in on the first part, and @Krzysztof Koźmic could advise me on why I had to comment out the trace logger.

Comment: Where did you get the source code from. i downloaded a version from https://github.com/castleproject but unable to even load the project in the solution. It keeps telling me incompatible version. Could you please share the updated library you built. thanks